# flutter app take background location doesn't work on android 12

Tags: flutter, location

I have flutter app that I want to take user location from it even while in the background the app is running in android 9 well but on android 12 the background location and function doesn't work this is my code

```
static void liveLocation()async{
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.reload();
    print('hello from live location method');
    double? storedLongitude=prefs.getDouble('trackingLongitude');
    double? storedlatitude=prefs.getDouble('trackingLatitude');
    String? empname=prefs.getString('empname');
    print('stored latlong is $storedLongitude , $storedlatitude');
    final trackingLocation =await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    print(trackingLocation.latitude);
    print(trackingLocation.longitude);
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat =
    (trackingLocation.latitude! - storedlatitude!)*pi/180; // deg2rad below
    var dLon = (trackingLocation.longitude! - storedLongitude!)*pi/180;
    var a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) +
        cos((trackingLocation.latitude!)*pi/180) *
            cos((storedlatitude)*pi/180) *
            sin(dLon / 2) *
            sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c * 1000; // Distance in km
      prefs.setDouble('trackingLongitude', trackingLocation.longitude);
      prefs.setDouble('trackingLatitude', trackingLocation.latitude);
      await prefs.reload();
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(tasksCollectionName).doc(empname)
          .collection("location").doc("location")
          .set(
          {
            'latitude': trackingLocation.latitude,
            'longitude': trackingLocation.longitude,
            'arriveTime': DateTime.now().toString().substring(11, 16),
          });
    
  }
  double deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (pi / 180);
  }
```

and here where I call the function using androidAlarmManager.periodic package

```
AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), 1,

                       liveLocation);
```

I added the permission to manifest and change location setting from device setting to always enable
but nothing work with me
Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you tried getting the location natively in Android with Java or Kotlin then passing the location back using platform channels?

Comment: no cause I don't know how to do that but is that working on background and in pereodic time ? to try this or you don't know if it's working or not thanks for your comment